# IIS7 rewrite rule triggers 404 rather than redirecting to new pagw

Tags: 404, iis7, 302-redirect, web.config

We recently replaced most of our default pages from default.htm to default.asp.

Rewrite rules work fine if it's a sub-folder, e.g. example.com/help/default.asp where the default.htm was deleted.  If I type domain.com/help/default.htm, it correctly shows the new .asp page and no 404 because the default.htm no longer exists.

At the root entering example.com/default.htm does not redirect to default.asp instead sending the user to the 404 page we created.

Tried exact match vs. wildcard, no difference.

Why the 404 and no redirect?

```
<rule name="homepage" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="*example.com/default.htm" ignoreCase="true" />
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/default.asp" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

---

**UPDATE:** This works on a subfolder redirect from htm to asp:

```
<rule name="downloadhome" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="*download/default.htm" ignoreCase="true" />
<action type="Redirect" url="/download/default.asp" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: What rule were you using to match your subfolders?

Comment: This works on a subfolder redirect from htm to asp:

Comment: <rule name="downloadhome" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="*download/default.htm" ignoreCase="true" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="/download/default.asp" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <match url="*example.com/default.htm" ignoreCase="true" />
> ```

I think the `url` attribute matches against the URL-path only, not the hostname. So the above should read:

```
<match url="^default\.htm" ignoreCase="true" />
```

This matches "default.htm" in the document root, or use the pattern `default\.htm` to match "default.htm" anywhere.

This uses `patternSyntax="ECMAScript"` on the `<rule>` (to use regular expressions). Or just remove the `patternSyntax` attribute entirely, since this is the default option

---

To have just one rule for both scenarios: a request for the document root and a subdirectory then you could probably do something like the following instead:

```
<rule name="replacedefaulthtm" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)default\.htm$" ignoreCase="true" />
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}default.asp" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Where `{R:1}` is a backreference to the captured subpattern `(.*)` in the preceding rule.

Comment: That worked with one change as follows:  `<rule name="replacedefaulthtm" stopProcessing="true"><match url="(.*)default.htm$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}default.asp" redirectType="Permanent" />redirectType="Permanent" />`
   </rule>`

Comment: Glad that resolved your problem. Are you saying that using an absolute URL (ie. `url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}default.asp"`) did not work at all or resulted in a malformed redirect or something? Minor fix to the above regex: the second dot in `(.*)default.htm$` should strictly be backslash-escaped, so should read `(.*)default\.htm$` (I've updated my answer).

Comment: I tested with the absolute URL and no redirect, but using the
`(.*)default.htm$`
did the trick.  No idea why but it did the job.